# disable forward operation videogular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, videogular

```js
import {VgCoreModule} from 'videogular2/core';
import {VgControlsModule} from 'videogular2/controls';
import {VgOverlayPlayModule} from 'videogular2/overlay-play';
import {VgBufferingModule} from 'videogular2/buffering';
```

```html
<div class="video-sec">
    <vg-player>
        <video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" controls>
            <source src="http://static.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </vg-player>
</div>
```

I'm using videogular video player in my angular 2 project. I want to disable forward operation of that video player as well as there is one download button is present so I also want to disable download operation of that player. How can I do this ?

Comment: Have you tried going through the docs?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `controlsList="nodownload"` in your video tag

```
<vg-player>
    <video ... controls controlsList="nodownload">
        <source src="xxxx" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</vg-player>
```